# Criar aplicação para comunicar com saída SYSFAN da placa mãe

Tags: java, c#, c, c++, assembly

Olá, estou precisando de uma ideia de biblioteca, linguagem, código, que vocês saibam onde posso escrever o código para comunicar com a saída do Fan da placa mãe.

Para entender melhor a ideia, existem aplicativos como SpeedFan que fazem este trabalho. 
Porém, preciso utilizar esta saída para controlar um dispositivo externo, pois a saída do fan da placa mãe é PWM + Tensão 12V. 
Quando altero a velocidade no aplicativo SpeedFan, consigo abaixar as tensões. 
Mas, preciso saber algum caminho para poder entender como alterar a saída da SYSFAN de acordo com meus cálculos. Dessa forma, meu dispositivo externo vai funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: Infelizmente o problema é "mais embaixo". Cada _vendor_ usa uma maneira diferente de controlar isso, e esses programas como SpeedFan só conseguem controlar muitas placas com ajuda da comunidade. A coisa mais próxima do que está pedindo é isso aqui: https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor que expõe uma série de coisas ao WMI no windows, por exemplo.

Comment: Se pretende controlar um dispositivo externo, talvez fosse melhor pensar em outra saída, como um conversor USB -> Centronics, por exemplo, assim você teria vários pinos de I/O independentes controlados a baixo custo (e pode implementar um escalonamento com ponte de resistor, ou algum dedicado binário->analógico) - Lembrando ainda que quando você mexe na ventoinha, em muitos casos não está alterando a voltagem, e sim o espaço entre os pulsos de 12v (que é o PWM mencionado)

Comment: Outra delas é pegar um freeduino (apesar de eu achar um exagero) e adequar à sua necessidade.

Comment: Eu usaria arduino, ou algum CI programável, com comunicação via porta serial. Não é uma boa ficar mexendo neste tipo de componente, porque a placa mãe, pode querer controlar ela mesma essa saída, tem muita chance de dar errado. Principalmente em momentos de boot e reboot onde a bios toma conta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Enfim, pensei em usar a saída USB para realizar comunicação. Dessa forma irei ter que procurar conteúdo sobre comunicação serial ?